# How to import functioning HTML programs into Bootstrap project?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-studio

I am new to Bootstrap Studio and am pretty much learning everything as I go!
I am creating front end pages for a school software project. I have written a chat box program in HTML and CSS and would like to include that inside the pages I am designing with Bootstrap Studio.
I don’t have problem importing the files, I am just not sure how can I include the chat box in the project.
The only thing I could think of was to place a Form then convert it into HTML and paste my code there, however that didn’t work and I am still confused on how to also use the CSS file which I have imported.
Really appreciate it if you could point me to the right direction.